# v13: ListPlot and TimeSeries

Tags: plotting, bugs, date-and-time, version-13

**Note:** Fixed in version 13.1. Bug present in version 13.0.

The examples from the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) for `TimeSeries` behave strangely in v13.0.  Here's the first:

```
v = {2, 1, 6, 5, 7, 4};
t = {1, 2, 5, 10, 12, 15};
ts = TimeSeries[v, {t}];
ListLinePlot[ts]
```

[image]

One can get the old behavior back with `Normal`:

```
ListLinePlot[Normal@ts]
```

[image]

This seems related to the section **Dates, and Infinities, in Plot Scales** [here](https://blog.wolfram.com/2021/12/13/launching-version-13-0-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/).  Should we consider this new behavior a bug or an intended change?

*Addendum:*

The behavior of `ListLogPlot` remains unchanged:

```
ListLogPlot[ts]
```

[image]

Comment: I think if you plot a time series, the x axis should show time not numbers

Comment: And in this case, the time specification `t` of the `TimeSeries` is in seconds, which plots correctly under v13.

Comment: @DanielHuber I will report it in any case, because the documentation for `TimeSeries` reflects the old behavior throughout.  Personally, I think the old behavior is preferable. The docpage for `TimeSeries` says "The $t_i$ can be numbers or any valid input to AbsoluteTime." so why assume these are times not numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine it's intentional, but you can also retrieve the old behavior through [`ScalingFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html):

```
ListLinePlot[ts, ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear"}]
```

[image]